# undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_mutexattr_setpshared@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: c++, c, boost, mpi, undefined-reference

I tried to add -lpthread but it didn't work. here is my makefile:

```
mpi_bench: mpbench.o flushall.o timer.o my_send.o mem_manager.o
    $(MP_MPI_CC) $(MP_LDFLAGS)  mpbench.o flushall.o timer.o my_send.o mem_manager.o -o $@ $(MPI_LIBS) $(MP_LIBS)

mpbench.o: mpbench.c
    $(MP_MPI_CC) $(MP_CFLAGS) $(MPI_INC) -DMPI -I.. -c  mpbench.c  -o mpbench.o 

timer.o: ../timer.c
    $(MP_MPI_CC) -c -I.. ../timer.c -o $@ 

flushall.o: ../flushall.c
    $(MP_MPI_CC) -c -I.. ../flushall.c -o $@  

my_send.o: my_send.cpp
    $(MP_MPI_CC)  -c -I.. my_send.cpp -o my_send.o -lrt 
mem_manager.o: mem_manager.cpp
    $(MP_MPI_CC)  -c -I.. mem_manager.cpp -o mem_manager.o -lrt -lpthread
```

here is the error information

```
mpicc   mpbench.o flushall.o timer.o my_send.o mem_manager.o -o mpi_bench  -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: mem_manager.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_mutexattr_setpshared@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

can anyone a help me out? thank you so much

Comment: The problem is, that 'object' files are not linked at all, an application is. You need to add the `-lrt` and `-lpthread` directives to the steps, where you assemble your object files into the application.

Comment: *Where* on the command line did you try to add `-pthread`? And only when compiling the spource files into object files, or also when linking the object files into the executable?

Comment: You should never use -lpthread. Use -pthread instead when both compiling and linking.

Comment: thanks guys, the problem was solved after i add -lpthread to where objects linked

Comment: `-pthread` works well with GNU compilers but is not portable (for example, PGI compilers do (did?) not support it). never say never ;-)